# return true if two elements having same class using operators in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, operators

i have two elements with ids `#online` and `#offline`, where i want to check whether both these elements having a specific class `.selected`using AND operator in selector. Something like,

```
$("[id='online']&&[id='offline']").hasClass('selected');
```

If **both these elements having** `selected` class, it should return a **`true`** else **`false`**;

Is this possible in jquery?

I know it can be done like this,

```
($("[id='offline']").hasClass('selected') && $("[id='online']").hasClass('selected'))
```

But looking for a simplified implementation of same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `.filter()` along with `multiple selector` to achieve your need,

```
$('#online,#offline').filter('.selected').length == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether any of the do not have the class like

```
$("#online, #offline").not('.selected').length == 0
```

Note: Use ID selector when you can